# Does a druid count as hitting 0 HP before reverting out of Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, hit-points

So a druid is in Wild Shape and takes damage over the threshold by a gnoll. So she turns back into her real form and takes the remaining damage in real form. The gnoll has a trait called Rampage, meaning when it reduces a creature to 0 HP, it gets another attack.

Would taking a wild-shaped druid down count as taking a creature down to 0 HP?

Comment: OK, I've cleaned things up for you a bit now that we have enough information. But for future reference, I suggest you take a look at the [Tour]; we do things a little differently here. For one thing, we like question titles that indicate what the question is (not just what it's about), and the best place for systems and/or editions is in the tags, not the title. Otherwise, good question, and I hope you like it here.

Comment: @KRyan Looks like it's 5e based on the gnoll rampage ability.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll make sure to be more specific next time @KRyan

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's the text of the Gnoll's ability ([as found on page 317 of the pdf SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd)):

> **Rampage.** When the gnoll reduces a creature to 0 hit points with a melee attack on its turn, the gnoll can take a bonus action to move up
>   to half its speed and make a bite attack.

And Wild Shape says:

> You   automatically   revert  if  you fall unconscious,   drop    to  0   hit points, or  die.

In order for the druid to revert out of wild shape, they have to drop to 0 hit points. If they do so as a result of the gnoll's attack, it clearly *did* drop a creature to 0 hit points, and should be able to use Rampage. The fact that the creature suddenly turns into a different one that has more than 0 hit points doesn't matter.

Comment: The question has been updated with the system, so you no longer need to operate on any assumption. In general, though, *please do not answer unclear questions.* If you are *absolutely certain* you can try to clarify a question yourself, but unclear questions should not get answers until they are clarified, because if you assume wrong, you are only introducing clutter and confusion.