# How does concentration work when wild shape is ended through damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, damage, wild-shape, concentration

Consider the following situation (round numbers chosen for easier calculations):

- Bob is a human druid.
- In caster form Bob has a +0 CON modifier and 100 current HP.
- Bob is concentrating on a spell.
- Bob is wild-shaped. His current beast form has a +5 CON modifier and a current HP of 30.

What concentration checks are required (including DC and modifier used on the roll) if:

1. Bob is dealt 30 damage
2. Bob is dealt 60 damage

As far as I know concentration is not automatically broken in either situation because although [the druid counts as hitting 0 HP](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78051/does-a-druid-count-as-hitting-0-hp-before-reverting-out-of-wild-shape) he is never unconscious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### What the Rules Say

> **Whenever you take damage** while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever number is higher.

Means that when you have taken damage.  This is different than other effects that happen "when you are hit" like Shield:

> Casting Time: 1 reaction, which you take **when you are
>   hit** by an attack or targeted by the magic missile spell

This difference, as evidenced by the two difference sets of language, mean that the order is:

1. You are hit
2. Reactions and effects that trigger on hit
3. Take damage (HP changes)
4. Reactions and effects that trigger on damage

this is covered in a question about Hellish Rebuke: [Hellish Rebuke reaction with zero hitpoints](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77082/hellish-rebuke-reaction-with-zero-hitpoints)

### In This Case

The above applied means that the druid who takes damage that drops their wild shape form would use their own, not the beast form's, CON Save for the check. Both would be Bob's Con.

So following the list...

#### 30 damage

1. Hit happens.
2. No on hit events.
3. Damage happens, reduced to zero, form dropped.
4. Concentration check against Bob's CON Save vs DC 15.

#### 60 Damage

1. Hit happens.
2. No on hit events.
3. Damage happens, reduced to zero, form dropped, Bob takes 30 rollover damage.
4. Concentration check against Bob's CON Save vs DC 30.

#### Extra example to prove case

There is an class feature in Barbarian class:

> **Retaliation.** Starting at 14th level, when you take damage from
>   a creature that is within 5 feet of you. You can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature.

Given this, following the idea Miniman posted that taking damage effects happens before the damage.  The Barbarian is reduced to zero, and then gets a reaction (after being knocked unconscious) that allows him to make another attack.  When it is clear that the barbarian would be eating dirt not still swinging.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty simple, actually.

> **Whenever you take damage** while
>   you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a
>   Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration.
>   The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take,
>   whichever number is higher.

You make a Constitution saving throw "whenever you take damage". So when you take 30 damage, you make a Constitution saving throw. Since you make this when you take the damage, you use the stats you have when you take the damage. So it will be a DC 15 Constitution saving throw which you make with a +5 bonus.

The same reasoning applies to the 60 damage case. So when you take 60 damage, you make a DC 30 Constitution saving throw using a +5 bonus. There is a caveat, though.

> When
>   you
>   revert
>   to
>   your
>   normal
>   form,
>   you
>   return
>   to
>   the
>   number
>   of
>   hit
>   points
>   you
>   had
>   before
>   you
>   transformed.
>   However,
>   if
>   you
>   revert
>   as
>   a
>   result
>   of
>   dropping
>   to
>   0
>   hit
>   points,
>   any
>   excess
>   damage
>   carries
>   over
>   to
>   your
>   normal
>   form.
>   For
>   example,
>   if
>   you
>   take
>   10
>   damage
>   in
>   animal
>   form
>   and
>   have
>   only
>   1
>   hit
>   point
>   left,
>   you
>   revert
>   and
>   **take
>   9
>   damage.**

This suggests that the 30 carryover damage will count as being taken, so you'll have to make *another* Constitution saving throw, this time at DC 15, using your own +0 modifier.

Comment: I am not sure "carries over" means it counts as a separate source of damage. Had they worded it "if you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, you receive any excess damage to your normal form" it would be unambiguous. Maybe someone has asked the Wizards about this?

Comment: @kviiri Sorry, I was suggesting that it counts because of the wording in the example. I looked through Sage Advice and couldn't find any rulings on this issue.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I only looked at the polymorph rules but the druid rules are a bit more verbose on this. It's impossible to say which way was intended but your interpretation is sound.

Comment: You've already made the Con saving throw for the damage.  You aren't taking additional damage ( a second instance of damage) all you are doing is making sure none of it goes to waste (Bookkeeping).

Comment: This seems reasonable but just to clarify you are saying that something that triggers "Whenever you take damage" happens before other consequences of such damage (like reverting from wild shape in this case or being knocked unconscious or dying)

Comment: @Sdjz Yep, exactly. The alternative would mean that, for example, you could be killed by damage you didn't actually take.

Comment: Nope, "When you are hit" and "When you take damage" are different.

Comment: @JAStreich For the simplest example, look at Primordial Ward from Elemental Evil.

Comment: Two saving throws from the same source of single damage doesnt make sense. And if you follow this logic, then only the damage requirrd to bring you to 0 in the wildshape form would count for the first daving throw. So if you had 30 HP as a bear, it would be dc 15 no matter what, and then a second throw in your other form.

Comment: Your answer here disagrees with your answer on Hellish Rebuke ( http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77082/hellish-rebuke-reaction-with-zero-hitpoints ).  You can't have it both ways. I believe your answer on Hellish Rebuke is correct, and this one is mistaken. Moreover, the statement "including against the triggering damage" is a specific exception to the general rule.

Comment: @J.A.Streich "You can't have it both ways" isn't really true. The rules around this are more than a little ill-defined. In that answer, I went with one interpretation, and in this one, I've gone with another.