# Can the Shepherd druid's "Faithful Summons" feature be triggered by losing all HP in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape, hit-points

The [Circle of the Shepherd druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleoftheShepherd) gets the Faithful Summons feature at 14th level (XGtE, p. 24):

> If you are reduced to 0 hit points or are incapacitated against your will, you can immediately gain the benefits of *conjure animals* as if it were cast using a 9th-level spell slot.

Can you gain the benefits of the Faithful Summons feature if you are in Wild Shape and your new form's HP is reduced to 0?

Comment: Very related, possible duplicate: [Does a druid count as hitting 0 HP before reverting out of Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78051/does-a-druid-count-as-hitting-0-hp-before-reverting-out-of-wild-shape)

Comment: _Very_ nice catch